# UI bug pushing UIActivityViewController in UINavigationController (via popover) on iPad running iOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios11, uiactivityviewcontroller

Pushing a UIActivityViewController used to appear fine on iOS 10 but as of iOS 11 it no longer automatically goes below the navigation bar. Thoughts? The code is pretty basic.

```
 let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
 navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

[image: Incorrect Y origin for UIActivityViewController]

Edit:
This is what happens when I present the UIActivityViewController inside the popover. I can resize the popover but can't detect when the UIActivityViewController dismisses to then resize back to its normal size, whereas this was all automatic when pushing.
[image: Incorrect UI when presenting UIActivityViewController]

Comment: Never push an `UIActivityViewController` onto a navigation controller. Call `present` on the `UIActivityViewController` after setting it up as a modal popover.

Answer (score -1):

You should not push an activity controller, this is the kind of view controller you want to present modally.
From Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller):

> On iPad, you must present the view controller in a popover. On iPhone
>   and iPod touch, you must present it modally.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I forgot to mention that this is happening on iPad.  The app is iPad only too if that helps.

Comment: As Apple say, on the iPad they it must be presented inside a popover. The behavior from 10 to 11 could be different because they aren't suppose to be used like that.

Comment: As you can see in the image it’s being presented in a popover, so I don’t know what else you want me to do  is the problem the UINavigationController? Because I’ve already got a popover and I can’t display a popover to another popover.

Comment: @SunburstEnzo, No, the code you posted clearly shows that you are pushing the UIActivityViewController on a navigation controller. You need to `present` the UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Ok I've updated the question with an example of presenting it and the problem it has doing it. Thoughts?